# how to access cookies on subdomain

Tags: php, session

i want to access the cookies on sub domain,

the cookies working on main domain well but can't able to access the cookie on subdomain, i created two files testing_1.php and testing_2.php, the cookies is set through testing_1.php that is

```
$domain = '.localhost';
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', $domain);
session_start();

$_SESSION['name'] = 'Jogesh';
setcookie("f_name", "jogesh", 0, "/", "$domain");

if( isset( $_COOKIE["f_name"] ) )
    echo "Set Cookie on 1: " . $_COOKIE["f_name"];
else
    var_dump(setcookie("f_name", "jogesh", 0, "/", "$domain"));
```

in the above code i also try to access session, but just got the session id, i want to access `$_SESSION['name']` on subdomain if possible other wise cookies

now the testing_2.php is here

```
session_start();

if( isset( $_SESSION['name'] ) )
    echo "Session Name: " . $_SESSION['name'];
else
    echo "Session not set!";

if( isset( $_COOKIE["f_name"] ) )
    echo "Cookie Name: " . $_COOKIE["f_name"];
else
    echo "Cookie not set!";
```

the both files working well on `localhost` but when i am trying to access the file testing_2.php from `demo.localhost` the can't access anything plz let me know what mistake i had done,,

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating them at `www.example.com` then you cannot read them from `cdn.example.com`. You have to create them at `example.com`. Also you cannot read PHP created cookies with JavaScript and visa-verse. It also depends on the browser. there were issues with `tsk.tr`. You have to see the browser's list http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1 Might me because the browser handles `localhost` and `subdomain.localhost` as complitly different domain names. Try the code in a real envirement or use [hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) file.

Comment: thanks, but what i used is wrong? cause i am testing on the localhost not on the main server, plz let me know thanks again 'EDIT:' i see that you said to use them on real environment, but why it is not working on localhost?? i mean the cookies

Comment: Browser's security measurements in order to prevent local fraud attacks I guess. Try 127.0.0.1 with demo.127.0.0.1 if it is possible. Or may be you should ask it to http://forums.mozillazine.org/